# The photos don't appear after an update to vTiger 6.2

Tags: image, updates, photo, vtiger, avatar

After an update or a fresh install of vtiger 6.2, it's possible that contact photos don't appear. It looks like a dead link.

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

vTiger 6.2 puts all your uploads (incl. user & product pictures) into /storage and denys access to this folder from the web through a htaccess-File (/storage/.htaccess):

```
deny from all
```

These files will only be accessible by the webserver/php directly, which is perfect from a security point of view and it should be kept that way (deleting this htaccess-file is a very bad thing, cause then everybody outside will be able to read your files given he has the right path)!!!

The correct way to deal with these files inside the Web-Application would be to never reference the files directly in HTML (`<img src="path/to/file">`, cause you would not see them due to the htaccess-File) but to always route their data through a gateway-PHP-Script which checks if the requesting user is authenticated (`<img src="file.php?filename=path/to/file">`). The PHP-Script can (as I said above) bypass the Apache/htaccess-Security cause it directly accesses the filesystem. This is done in the Document-Section where you can see that downloading a file leads to "http://domain/index.php?module=Documents&action=DownloadFile&record=10&fileid=11"

However, unfortunatly vTiger has places in its Web-Application where it still references files in /storage directly in HTML as with User Pictures and Product Pictures therefor they are not shown.

## UPDATE: Bugfix

I found that the Apps Contacts, Users and Products have this problem.
I bugfixed them in 2 steps:

### Add Actions for each App as Gateway-Scripts

Create the files (vTiger is installed on /opt/vtiger)

*/opt/vtiger/modules/Users/actions/DownloadPicture.php*

```
<?php

class Users_DownloadPicture_Action extends Vtiger_Action_Controller {

    public function checkPermission(Vtiger_Request $request) {
            $moduleName = $request->getModule();

            if(!Users_Privileges_Model::isPermitted($moduleName, 'DetailView', $request->get('record'))) {
                    throw new AppException(vtranslate('LBL_PERMISSION_DENIED', $moduleName));
            }
    }

    public function process(Vtiger_Request $request) {

            $userRecordModel = Vtiger_Record_Model::getInstanceById($request->get('record'), $request->getModule());
            $userPictureDetails = $userRecordModel->getImageDetails();
            $pictureData = file_get_contents($userPictureDetails[0]['path'] . '_' . $userPictureDetails[0]['orgname']);

            header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            header("Pragma: public");
            header("Cache-Control: private");

            echo $pictureData;

    }
}

?>
```

*/opt/vtiger/modules/Products/actions/DownloadPicture.php*

The same but: `class Products_Download...`

*/opt/vtiger/modules/Contacts/actions/DownloadPicture.php*

The same but: `class Contacts_Download...`

### Adapt the Templates to serve Image-Tags with the Gateway-Script

Go in the files, find the `<img ... >`-Tag and change its src-Attribute:

*/opt/vtiger/layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/ListViewContents.tpl*

```
index.php?module={$MODULE}&action=DownloadPicture&record={$LISTVIEW_ENTRY->get('id')}
```

*/opt/vtiger/layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/PreferenceDetailViewHeader.tpl*

```
index.php?module={$MODULE}&action=DownloadPicture&record={$RECORD->get('id')}
```

*/opt/vtiger/layouts/vlayout/modules/Users/UserViewHeader.tpl*

```
index.php?module={$MODULE}&action=DownloadPicture&record={$RECORD->get('id')}
```

*/opt/vtiger/layouts/vlayout/modules/Vtiger/DetailViewBlockView.tpl*

```
index.php?module={$MODULE}&action=DownloadPicture&record={$RECORD->get('id')}
```

*/opt/vtiger/layouts/vlayout/modules/Vtiger/uitypes/Image.tpl*

```
index.php?module={$MODULE}&action=DownloadPicture&record={$RECORD_ID}
```

*/opt/vtiger/layouts/vlayout/modules/Contacts/DetailViewHeaderTitle.tpl*

```
index.php?module={$MODULE}&action=DownloadPicture&record={$RECORD->get('id')}
```

Now it is for sure you can see your pictures everywhere, but without beeing logged in you cannot access the files!

Possible open problem: I do not know so much about rights management in vTiger to tell you that now only users with access rights on the records have access to the files. It is possible that now every user can access them. If somebody knows how to control this. Please comment!

Hope everything works out, as by me.

Servus
Lukas

Comment: THANKS for this, I have implemented it and it is mostly working very well. But any idea how to add this to the comments module? It does not seem to be structured as the others are. (there is a user profile image trying to be pulled next to each commenter when comments are listed)

Answer (score -1):

To solve that, simply yourself connect to your server through an FTP client. Empty or remove the ".htaccess" file in the "/storage" folder.
That's it!

Answer (score -1):

Or in the .htaccess file change from:

```
deny from all
```

to:

```
Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score -1):

I rewrote my .htaccess file from "deny from all" to…

```
    # If the URI is an image then we allow accesses
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "\\.(gif|jpe?g|png|bmp)$" let_me_in

    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    # Allow accesses only if an images was requested
    Allow from env=let_me_in
```

Now my images show up.